# Cannot find ContentTypeReader

Tags: c#, windows, xna

I have found a number of threads on this error but I haven't found a solution. I am using a number of class libraries from XNAExpert.com that are designed to animate a skinned mesh. I'm using XNA 4.0, Win Xp and programming games for Windows. Here is complete error:

Cannot find ContentTypeReader SkinnedModel.SkeletonReader, SkinnedModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.

The tutorial can be found [here](http://www.xnaexpert.com/English/tutorials.html) . Here is the code from the reader class within SkinnedModel project:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;

namespace SkinnedModel
{
    public class SkeletonReader : ContentTypeReader<Skeleton>
    {
        protected override Skeleton Read(ContentReader input, Skeleton existingInstance)
        {
            List<Bone> boneList = input.ReadObject<List<Bone>>();
            return new Skeleton(boneList);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code from the writer class from within SkinnedModelProcessor project:

```
[ContentTypeWriter]
    public class SkeletonWriter : ContentTypeWriter<Skeleton>
    {
        protected override void Write(ContentWriter output, Skeleton value)
        {
            output.WriteObject(value.BoneList);
        }

        public override string GetRuntimeReader(TargetPlatform targetPlatform)
        {
            return typeof(SkeletonReader).AssemblyQualifiedName;
        }
    }
```

As you can see the type returned is the Assembly Qualified Name for each reader...Is anyone aware of another reason why I may be having trouble?

Answer (score 2):

Solution for me was to just delete the ContentTypeReader and create a new one.

My problem seemed to be caused by having a mirrored project (I had Windows game library and Windows Phone game library). On Windows client the ContentReader was successfully found, but not on the Windows Phone client.

Answer (score 0):

As i read it the SkeletonReader is known to the SkeletonWriter. I cannot think of a valid way to setup the projects so that this is true.

- Project Main (Links To Content)

  - SkeletonReader
  - Skeleton

---

- Project Content (Links To ContentExtendion)

  - SkeletonFile (Has Processor set to SkeletonProcessor)

---

- Project ContentExtendion *(Cannot link circular)*

  - SkeletonContent (Is Input For Writer)
  - SkeletonWriter
  - SkeletonProcessor

Look at your ProjectSetup i think your assemblies are not linked correctly.
And return a fixed string in GetRuntimeReader - if you setup the projects correctly you will loose the connection to the SkeletonReader.

There is a [quite complete tutorial on the content pipeline](http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/content-pipeline-extension-1) on the interwebs.